# Class Array - Collect data from department in for loop (Two different kinds of types)

Tags: java, algorithm, class

I wrote the following exercise but I have a little problem.
After I add workers into the array I want to calculate the salary of all workers together.

What is wrong function? And how I take from employee salary and put into a variable?

this the function (into Department class):

I get a compiler error, I try to run the calculateSalary function So that each iteration of a loop that passes I is considered the employee's salary and the amount at the end of the salaries togethe.

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrWork.length; i++) {

    Compile error>> this.calculateSalary(arrWork[i]); 

        Compile error>> sumSalary+=arrWork[i];
    }

}
```

Worker class:

```
public class Worker {

private String id;
private String name;
private int hourly_wage;
public  int num_hours;


//constructor
public Worker(String id,String name,int hourly_wage,int num_hours){
this.id = id;
this.name = name;
this.hourly_wage = hourly_wage;
this.num_hours = num_hours;
}

public Worker(){

}

//copy constructor
public Worker(Worker other){
    this.id = other.id;
    this.name = other.name;
    this.hourly_wage = other.hourly_wage;
    this.num_hours = other.num_hours;
}

public String getID(){
    return this.id;
}
public void setID(String id){
    this.id = id;
}
public String getNAME(){
    return this.name;
}
public void setNAME(String name){
    this.name = name;
}
public int getHW(){
    return this.hourly_wage;
}
public void setHW(int hourly_wage){
    this.hourly_wage = hourly_wage;;
}
public int getNH(){
    return this.num_hours;
}
public void setNH(int num_hours){
    this.num_hours = num_hours;
}



public void addHours(int n){
    this.num_hours+=n;
}   
public void clearHours(){
    this.num_hours=0;
}
public void calculateSalary(int n){
    double sum=0;
    if(n<=this.num_hours){
        sum=n*this.hourly_wage;
        System.out.println("The salary is: "  + sum);
    }
    else if(n>this.num_hours){
        sum= n - this.num_hours;
        sum= sum * (this.hourly_wage * 1.2);
        sum+= this.num_hours*this.hourly_wage;
        System.out.println("The salary is: "  + sum);
    }
}

public String toString(){
    return "NAME: "+this.name+", ID: "+this.id+", HOURLY WAGE: "+ this.hourly_wage+
    " ,NUM HOURS: "+this.num_hours;
}

}
```

Department class:

```
public class Department extends Worker {
private String D_name;
private int A_budget;
private Worker[] arrWork;
private int Index;
public int MAX_WORKERS;

public Department(int max_workers){
    this.MAX_WORKERS = max_workers;
    arrWork= new Worker[this.MAX_WORKERS];
    Index=0;
}

public String getD_NAME(){
    return this.D_name;
}
public void setD_NAME(String D_name){
    this.D_name = D_name;
}
public int getA_BUDGET(){
    return this.A_budget;
}
public void setA_BUDGET(int A_budget){

    this.A_budget = A_budget;
}

public void addEmploy(String id,String name,int hourly_wage,
        int num_hours){
    arrWork[Index] = new Worker(id,name,hourly_wage,num_hours);
    Index++;
}
public void calculateDepartmentSalary(){
    int sumSalary=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arrWork.length; i++) {

    }
}

public void print(){
    for (int i = 0; i < arrWork.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(arrWork[i]);
    }
}

}
```

main:

```
public class main {
public static void main(String[]args){

    Worker w1 = new Worker ("liran","123",25,80);

    System.out.println(w1);
    w1.calculateSalary(90);

    Department d1 = new Department(5);


    d1.setD_NAME("sapir");
    d1.setA_BUDGET(20000);

    d1.addEmploy("123", "liran", 25, 80);
    d1.addEmploy("234", "yosi", 29, 70);
    d1.addEmploy("456", "david", 26, 90);

    d1.print();

    d1.calculateDepartmentSalary();


}
}
```

thank's

Comment: Show us all the error message you get

Comment: I get a compile error in the function's attributes

Comment: But what say the error? Show us the message the compiler gives you

Comment: The method calculateSalary(double) in the type Worker is not applicable for the arguments (Worker).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the compiler error, unless you tell me about the compiler error message. 
But one more thing I observed in your code: If the code is supposed to calculate the salaries altogether, then the method `calculateSalary(int n)` in `Worker class` should return the salary. Currently it is returning nothing (void). And then in following for loop below you should add the returned salary of the worker in each iteration of for loop.

```
public double calculateSalary(int n){
    double sum=0;
    if(n<=this.num_hours){
        sum=n*this.hourly_wage;
        System.out.println("The salary is: "  + sum);
    }
    else if(n>this.num_hours){
        sum= n - this.num_hours;
        sum= sum * (this.hourly_wage * 1.2);
        sum+= this.num_hours*this.hourly_wage;
        System.out.println("The salary is: "  + sum);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Modified for loop, to calculate salaries of workers altogether:

```
 double sumSalary = 0;

 for (int i = 0; i < arrWork.length; i++) {
    sumSalary += this.calculateSalary(arrWork[i].getNH()); 
 }
```

Comment: i will changed my code but stiil compile error.                                          this the error: The method calculateSalary(double) in the type Worker is not applicable for the arguments (Worker).  i understand the error but not successful.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the above for loop with below change, I have edited the previos answer as well..provided *arrWork* is the array of type *Worker*.

```
arrWork[i] --> arrWork[i].getNH()
```

I think it should work now.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < arrWork.length; i++) {
    sumSalary += this.calculateSalary(arrWork[i].getNH()); 
 }
```

Comment: i try but run time error:  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at classWorkers.Department.calculateDepartmentSalary(Department.java:39)
 at classWorkers.main.main(main.java:24)

Answer (score 0):

For NullPointerException...

In the below code, you are making the department object with max_workers = 5.
It will initialize the array with length 5, now you have only added 3 workers in the array, so last two entries are still null. I think it is the reason of NullPointerException.

```
Department d1 = new Department(5);

d1.setD_NAME("sapir");
d1.setA_BUDGET(20000);

d1.addEmploy("123", "liran", 25, 80);
d1.addEmploy("234", "yosi", 29, 70);
d1.addEmploy("456", "david", 26, 90);

d1.print();
d1.calculateDepartmentSalary();
```

Comment: i succesful the solution is:                                                            sumSalary+= arrWork[i].calculateSalary(arrWork[i].getNH());                                I tried to activate the function on this and this wrong, i active the function on arrWork[i] and now this working well.